# Rails4 - How to access constants in a view and display them correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have constants like following in my user model

app/models/user.rb

```
GENDER_TYPES = [['Male', false], ['Female', true]]
COUNTRY_TYPES = [["Afghanistan",1],["Aland Islands",2],["Albania",3]..]
```

In views like user sign up page I access them as follows

```
  <div>
  <%= f.label :is_female, "Gender" %>
  <%= f.select :is_female,  User::GENDER_TYPES , {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
  </div>

  <div>
  <%= f.label :country, "From" %>
  <%= f.select :country,  User::COUNTRY_TYPES , {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>
  </div>
```

This is part of my user model

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change    

    add_column :users, :is_female, :boolean, default: false   
    add_column :users, :country, :integer

  end
end
```

When a user signs up, I am able to store the data in the table.
But when I display a user in views, I am using something like this for gender

```
  <% if user.is_female %>
    <small>Female</small>
  <% else %>
    <small>Male</small>
  <% end %>
```

And I don't know how to do it for country.
I know there must be better way to do it.

Can someone kindly share how to display user's gender and country which has the above mentioned datastructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you're settled with holding your data in constants, here are few tips:

- use hashes: `COUNTRIES = {1 => "Afghanistan"}`, you can easily convert that to array of pairs if necessary and you can easily lookup values in both ways:

> ```
> <% if user.country %>
>   <%= User::COUNTRIES[user.country] %>
> <% end %>
> ```

- use helpers to present raw data instead of referencing model constants directly, it is also useful when you want to do translations which are part of presentation, not business logic:

> ```
> def coutries_for_select
>   # assuming countries is a hash id => name
>   User::COUNTRIES.map {|id, name| [name, id]}
> end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

May not be perfect, but will do the job

```
<%= User::COUNTRY_TYPES.map(&:reverse).to_h[user.country] %>
```

It is better to save the countries in another table, and reference it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But I took this approach so that I can stop database access. I have a view where users can see all the other users. I thought if i save country in a database then there will an access to the database for every user. For instance if a page shows 30 users, won't there by 30 access to the database? Sorry am a newbie. Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @LovingRails you are semi-right, what you're describing is called N+1 problem and rails allows you to avoid it: `User.includes(:countries).all`, will generate 2 database queries and attach corresponding country to each selected user. more details here: https://www.codemy.net/posts/optimizing-your-rails-app-part-1-n-1-queries

Comment: You can eager load the countries when you fetch the users, which will limit the number of queries to 2.